# HTTPS security issue

Tags: https

I want to learn if my ISP or any Firewall or anybody else can see the links I browse which has ssl support ?

for exemple: 
when I browse google using secure search (https://google.com)

https://www.google.com.tr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&safe=active&sclient=psy-ab&q=any+search+term&oq=any+search+term&aq=f&aqi=g-v1&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=13935l17752l3l18016l16l15l0l1l1l0l306l1791l9.5.0.1l17l0&gs_l=hp.3..0i15.13935l17752l3l18016l16l15l0l1l1l0l306l1791l9j5j0j1l17l0.llsin&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=43e7b3983c4556bc&ion=1&biw=1366&bih=653

can anyone see the url I visited ?

Thanks. I know that SSL is there for security but I want to be sure if it's secure as we know it or is there any way some one can see what I am browsing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They CAN see the links you're browsing to, but they can't tell anything in regards the information that is passed between you and the website (for example, if you're submitting your credit card details).